# Let the lengths of bases $AD$ and $BC$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ be $a$ and $b(a>b)$.

Tags: geometry

Let the lengths of bases $AD$ and $BC$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ be $a$ and $b(a>b)$.

$(a)$ find the length of the segment that the diagonal intercept on the midline
$(b)$ find the length of the segment $MN$ whose endpoints divide $AB$ and $CD$ in the ratio $AM:MB = DN:NC = p:q$

I was able to solve the $(a)$ part by letting $PQ$ be the midline segment, then the diagonals $AC$ and  $BD$ intercept $PQ$ at points $K$ and $L$ respectively, then

$PK = \frac {1} {2} b$ and 
$PL = \frac {1} {2} a$ Hence

$KL = PL - PK = \frac {1}{2}(a-b)$

But I don't know how to proceed for the $(b)$ part.

Comment: You should put some description of the problem in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I've misread; I thought the problem was looking for the length with endpoints at the diagonals, not the legs of the trapezoid. But my idea for expressing MN when M is on DC and N is on AB, and AN:NB=DM:MC=p:q stays the same.

First of all, extend DC and AB over C and B and mark E as the intersection of those 2 lines. Let T be a point on AE such that MT is parallel to DA. For that point T, by Intercept theorem this will be true: AT:TE=DM:ME.

Since AN:NE=DM:ME=p:q, we condclude AT:TE=AN:NE. We know both T and N are on BA,
and are therefore co-linear. Logically, T is the only point on AE such that
AT:TE=AN:NE, so therefore we conclude N is T. Therefore, NM is parallel to DA.

Let P be the intersection of MN and DB, and Q the intersection of MN and CA. By Intercept theorem, you can conclude that MP is pb/(p+q), and that PN is qa/(p+q), so MN=MP+PN=(aq+bp)/(p+q).

Comment: your notation is quite confusing, do you mean that $P$ is a point on $MN$?

Comment: Yes, P is the intersection of MN and DC and Q is the intersection of MN and AB

Comment: @InkeretBear sorry but I still don't get it, in part (b) of the problem above, points $M$ and $N$ are supposed to lie on side $AB$ and $DC$, respectively. Now what intersection are you talking about? You mean the intersection of $MN$ and the diagonals of $ABCD$? How did you label your trapezoid? Can you send a rough sketch or something?, maybe that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is, you have a trapezoid with parallel sides being AD and BC. Now, select a point P on DC and a point Q on AB, such that PQ is parallel to AD and BC. M is the intersection of PQ with DB, and N is the intersection on PQ with AC. That's the points I worked with.

Comment: now I get what you were saying but I'm quite uncomfortably with your assumption that $PQ$ is parallel to $AD$ and $BC$, this was the condition given in part(a) of the problem above, if any line segment divides the sides of a trapezoid, must it necessarily have to be parallel to the bases except in the special case when the ratios are equal?. Secondly, you define $MN$ to be the length that $PQ$ intercepts on the diagonals, but this is not what part(b) asked for, part(b) assumed that points $M$ and $N$ touch the sides $AB$ and $CD$, respectively(dividing them in a given ratio).

Comment: It's not an assumption, you can extend CD over C and AB over B and mark E as the intersection of those two lines, then you'll have a triangle. Since CB is parallel to AD, you can apply Intercept theory again and realize EC:CD=EB:BA, and since DP:PC=AQ:QB, you know DE:PE=AE:QE.

Comment: Therefore, you know PQ and AD are parallel, since EC:CD=EB:BA would only be the case if, by Intercept theorem, PQ and AD are parralel

Comment: But yeah, I've realized that I've misread the problem, so sorry.

Comment: your solution is correct, but the author gave an alternative solution which I don't understand, according to him. He said, select a point on $AD$ such that $BF\parallel  DF$ and then let $E$ be the intersection of $BF$ with $MN$, then went further to assert that $$ME = \frac{MB\cdot AF} {AM + MB}$$ 
 I don't understand how he got this result.